# Django User set attribute and reverse relationships

Tags: django

Im using the below code in my views.py page to render a html page. This piece of code is from a Django book and im trying to understand the bookmark_set attribute.

views.py

```
def user_page(request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404(u'Requested user not found')

    bookmarks = user.bookmark_set.all()

    template = get_template('user_page.html')

    variables = Context({'username':username, 'bookmarks':bookmarks})

    output = template.render(variables)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Link(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User)
    link  = models.ForeignKey(Link)
```

When I run this piece of code in my Python shell, I get the following error

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from bookmarks.models import *
user=User.object.get(id=1)
user.bookmark_set.all()
```

> Attribute Error: 'User' object has no attribute 'bookmark_set'

Why do I get this error?

How does the set attribute of the User work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bookmark_set` attribute provides a convenient way to traverse the reverse relationship, i.e. to get all of a user's bookmarks. You can read more about it [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects):

> Django also creates API accessors for the "other" side of the relationship -- the link from the related model to the model that defines the relationship. For example, a Blog object b has access to a list of all related Entry objects via the entry_set attribute: b.entry_set.all().

You can actually specify the name of the reverse relationship attribute by providing a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in your model:

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="bookmarks")

$ myuser.bookmarks.all()
```

Have you definitely created your models in the DB by running `python manage.py syncdb`? It looks like you are doing everything correctly

Comment: No problem. You should try to accept some more answers for your previous questions. Over 50% of your previous 59 questions are unaccepted - it'll give people more incentive to help you out in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but add this; `select_related()` it worked in my case.

```
user=User.object.select_related().get(id=1)
user.bookmark_set.all()
```